# É possível ter uma 'Partialview' em WPF?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, mvvm, partialview

Queria saber se é possível implementar o conceito de partialview em uma View WPF. Algo parecido com um sistema de abas, que altera o conteúdo do grid mas não altera o layout da view. Só preciso saber como fazer o conteúdo da view filha ser carregado dentro da view pai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sistema de abas em wpf existe o TabControl, onde dentro podem existir n TabItem, que são as abas propriamente ditas.

Ex:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Aba 1">

        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Aba 2">

        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado cara. Ajudou muito

Comment: Por nada amigo, que bom que era isso que você precisava!